# How can I get my returned class of specific strings of a txt file added to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getTopNames(state, gender, startYear, endYear):
    """
    Get the top names.
    :param state (str): The state, e.g. 'NY'
    :param gender (str): The gender, e.g. 'F'
    :param startYear (int): The starting year, e.g. 1969
    :param endYear (int): The ending year, e.g. 2010
    :return: The list of top Name objects
    :rtype: list
    """

    fileName = 'data/' + state + '.txt'
    i = startYear
    file = open(fileName)
    lst = list()
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.strip().split(",")
            print(fields)
            if fields[1] == gender and fields[2] == i:
                lst.append(createName( fields[3], fields[1], int(fields[2]), fields[0], int(fields[4])))
                i = i +1
            if i == endYear:
                break          
            if line == "":
                break
    print(lst)
    return lst

def createName(name, gender, year, state, occurrences):
    """
    Initialize and return a new Name object.
    :param fields (list of str): A list of strings that represent one line
        in the file, [state, gender, year, name, occurrences], e.g.
        ['AK', 'M', '2004', 'Justin', '23']
    :return: the new Name object
    :rtype: Name
 """
    return Name(name, gender, year, state, occurrences)
```

Not sure why but I can't get name class to be added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading *strings* from the file but are trying to compare part of that string with an integer:

```
if fields[1] == gender and fields[2] == i:
```

Here `i` is an integer, but `fields[2]` is a string. They'll never be equal. Convert the data to an integer *first*:

```
if fields[1] == gender and int(fields[2]) == i:
```

If your data is comma-separated, rather than split manually, consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
with open(fileName, 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for fields in reader:
```